# How to remove diamonded question marks from equations converted from OMML to MathType?

Tags: markdown, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown, mathtype

I have simple bookdown document with labeled LaTeX equation:

```
---
title: "Equation text"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
  bookdown::word_document2: default
---

Below is the binom equation

\begin{equation}
f\left(k\right)=\binom{n}{k}p^k\left(1-p\right)^{n-k} (\#eq:binom)
\end{equation}
```

With RStudio it Knits normally to PDF:

[image: pdf]

Also it knits to docx-document and I have OMML equation inside:

[image: docx]

But for some reason I need to have this equation in MathType form.
So I perform its conversion from OMML (*Word 2007 and late (OMML) equations*) to MathType (*MathType equations (OLE objects)*):

[image: OMML to MathType]

This procedure ends with equation in Word:

[image: MathType equation with diamonded question marks]

The question marks    have the following hex equivalent: `E2 80 81 E2 80 81`.

How can I remove these diamonded question marks? Or how can I avoid their appearance?

Ideally I need to have equation number on the right of equation.

Comment: so the problem only occurs after you do the conversion in word? then that's a word problem... maybe just fix it manually?

Comment: Yes, the problem occurs after conversion in Word. I hope I can get this fix automatically. It is very actual for document with 10-100 equations...

Comment: `E2 80 81` would be the em quad, c.f. https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128. Looks like a word issue to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved by installing all needed fonts from MathType's distribution manually to *C:/Windows/Fonts*.

The diamonds gone:

[image: diamonds gone]

Note: latex notation for diamonds was `\qquad` if someone is interested.