# Pandoc tex to docx conversion ignores whitespace commands in math mode

Tags: latex, docx, pandoc

I got some tex files format that needs to be converted to docx.
Converting with pandoc using `pandoc my.tex -o my.docx`

pandoc version:

```
pandoc 2.7
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.5.4, texmath 0.11.2.1, skylighting 0.7.7
```

All working perfect except some math formulas with whitespace, for ex:

```
$$ a \quad b $$
```

renders in docx math like

```
ab
```

tried all i know:

```
$$a \quad\qquad\ \;\:\!\, b$$
```

...and still got same result.

Is where any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Might be an issue with https://github.com/jgm/texmath, which pandoc uses... but I tried it and there is a space when I open it in LibreOffice... haven't Word installed.

Comment: Same with for me, looks fine in Word on a Mac. I guess this is a font issue, similar to the problem described in https://stackoverflow.com/q/54928343